# I tried installing tensorflow after making a virtual environment but it still didnt install

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, installation, virtualenv

I was trying to install tensorflow but it wasnt being solved. I eventually made a virtual environment and then tried installing tensorflow but it still didn't work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgqWJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28pDw.png)

I tried installing tensorflow.
Look my python version is 3.12(I know that tensorflow doesnt work with python3.12. I installed python3.11 but even when i select my interpreter as python3.11 i still dont get my installation

I have tried installing tensorflow via multiple ways.
Once i used: python -m install tensorflow
I used: pip install tensorflow

I made a venv, activated it then typed pip install tensorflow.

Comment: Make sure you are installing correctly with `python 3.11`

Comment: Please walk through the steps of your installation to demonstrate to others how you  are performing this installation. Additionally make sure that you exit your initial `virtualenv` when making the specification for the new Python version.

Comment: What does it mean that make sure i am installing correctly with python3.11?

Comment: did you try: `/path/to/python311 -m pip install tensorflow`? If so, what error do you get? "It does not work" is meaningless. Someone might just as well say the fix was "Make it work".

Comment: @JonSG I tried what you said it gave me this error:
https://imgur.com/a/XnuXhbU

Comment: You are typing it incorrectly

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The error has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Install Python3.11, then check what is it installed as (py or python?), I installed it as py so I typed:

```
py -m pip install tensorflow
```

in cmd and it worked.

Long answer:
Currently, `tensorflow` does not support python3.12.

This means you have have to install some other python version. I installed python3.11.

I tried to change the Python interpreter to 3.11 in VS code but this did not work.
After talking to some experts on Discord, I found I had installed Python 3.11 as py, not python. After running the above code in cmd, it worked.

Comment: Hi Muhammad Talha Khan, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)